# How to show that $k[x^2,xy,y^2] \cong k[u,v,w]/(uw - v^2)$

Tags: polynomials, commutative-algebra

I'm working through the exercises of Eisenbud's commutative algebra. I want to prove the isomorphism stated in the question. Assume that $k$ is a field of characteristic not $2$.

Here's what I've done. Consider the map $\phi : k[u,v,w] \to k[x^2,xy,y^2]$ determined by $\phi(u) = x^2, \phi(v) = xy, \phi(w) = y^2$. Clearly $\phi$ is onto so we want to determine its kernel. Moreover, it is clear that $(uw - v^2) \subseteq \ker \phi$. To show that $(uw - v^2)$ is the whole kernel, consider $p \in k[u,v,w]$ such that $p(x^2,xy,y^2) = 0$. At this point, I would want to say something like "we can replace $x$ and $y$ with $\pm\sqrt{u}$ and $\pm\sqrt{w}$ respectively, and obtain that $\pm\sqrt{uw}$ are roots of $p$ viewed as a polynomial over the ring $k[u,w]$." Then $uw - v^2$ divides $p$ as desired.

The end of the argument doesn't feel rigorous to me. Another concern I have is how do I know over what ring $uw - v^2$ would divide $p$? How do I know that it is not over the ring of rational functions in $u,w$ instead of the ring of polynomials?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the ideal $(uw - v^2)$ let's take $v^2 - uw$ to be the preferred generator, since it is monic in $v$ as a polynomial in $k[u,v,w] = k[u,w][v]$.  In  $R[v]$ for an arbitrary commutative ring $R$, did you know that there is unique division with remainder by each monic polynomial in $v$ (or a polynomial whose leading coefficient in $v$ is a unit in $R$)? That means for each $p(u,v,w) \in k[u,v,w]$ we can (uniquely) write
$$
p(u,v,w) = (v^2 - uw)q(u,v,w) + r(u,v,w)
$$
where $q(u,v,w)$ and $r(u,v,w)$ are in $k[u,w][v]$ with $r(u,v,w) = 0$ or $\deg_v(r(u,v,w)) < 2$. That means
$$
r(u,v,w) = a(u,w)v + b(u,w)
$$
for some $a(u,w)$ and $b(u,w)$ in $k[u,w]$.  Now use the condition $p(x^2,xy,y^2) = 0$ in $k[x,y]$ to prove $a(u,w) = 0$ and $b(u,w) = 0$ in $k[u,w]$ (that is, all of their coefficients in $k$ are $0$).This part requires some careful considerations.  And from $r(u,v,w) = 0$, you get $p(u,v,w) = (v^2-uw)q(u,v,w) \in (v^2 - uw)$.

Why are you assuming the field $k$ doesn't have characteristic $2$?

Comment: Amazing thank you, I wasn't aware of division for polynomials over an arbitrary ring. And the characteristic being not equal to $2$ is used elsewhere in the problem I mentioned, I included that in case it was important here.

Comment: If you read any proof of division with remainder for polynomials, the only problem that can occur is division by the leading coefficient of the polynomial you are dividing by. So when that leading coefficient is $1$, or more generally is a unit, you will not run into any problems like degree dropping when multiplying leading terms together.